# I want to update the salary for the employees whose joined last 6 years in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried this query, but I'm stuck in the `where` condition. Can anybody help me how to update the salary for the whose joined last 6 years?

Query:

```
update emp
set sal=sal+3000
where doj=(select doj from emp where doj)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Hopefully this will help :)**

```
update emp set sal=sal+3000 where doj>=sysdate-6*365 and doj<sysdate;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update emp
set sal = sal + 3000
where select datediff(day,doj,Getdate()) / 365.2425 >= 6
```

Comment: @user3156193 check this

Answer (score 0):

```
update emp
set sal=sal+3000
where doj=(select doj from abd where datepart(year,doj) between  2009 and 2015)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "between" clause

```
update emp
set sal=sal+3000
where doj between dateadd(year, -6, getdate()) and getdate()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
update emp 
set sal=sal+3000 
where datediff(doj,select getdate(),yy)<=6
```